# How to add couple of row into table in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to insert couple row into my table, i found some solution [Here from aspsnippets](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/425845/Insert-multiple-row-in-database-in-ASPNet-MVC-using-jQuery-Ajax/) but i try the code into my project, the alert comes up but the table doest not recieve any inserted data. Sorry for my bad english, i am new in ASP MVC. Currently im using MVC5 in my project

My View Code

```
  <table id="tblCustomers" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:150px">Name</th>
            <th style="width:150px">FINAL_STACK</th>
            <th style="width:150px">RAW_DATA</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Seismic item in ViewBag.seismics)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.FINAL_STACK</td>
                <td>@item.RAW_DATA</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="Remove(this)" /></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtFINAL_STACK" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtRAW_DATA" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save All" />
```

My js code

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
        var txtName = $("#txtName");
        var txtFINAL_STACK = $("#txtFINAL_STACK");
        var txtRAW_DATA = $("#txtRAW_DATA");
        var tBody = $("#tblCustomers > TBODY")[0];
        var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);
        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtName.val());
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtFINAL_STACK.val());
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtRAW_DATA.val());
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        var btnRemove = $("<input />");
        btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
        btnRemove.attr("onclick", "Remove(this);");
        btnRemove.val("Remove");
        cell.append(btnRemove);
        txtName.val("");
        txtFINAL_STACK.val("");
        txtRAW_DATA.val("");
    });

    function Remove(button) {
        var row = $(button).closest("TR");
        var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {
            var table = $("#tblCustomers")[0];
            table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
        }
    };

    $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
        var seismics = new Array();
        $("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var seismic = {};
            seismic.Name = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
            seismic.FINAL_STACK = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
            seismic.RAW_DATA = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
            seismics.push(seismic);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Seismic/Insert",
            data: JSON.stringify(seismics),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

My Controller

```
public JsonResult Insert(List<Seismic> seismics)
    {
        foreach (Seismic seismic in seismics)
        {
            string name = seismic.Name;
            string FINAL_STACK = seismic.FINAL_STACK;
            string RAW_DATA = seismic.RAW_DATA;
        }
        return Json(seismics);

    }
```

My Model

```
public class Seismic
{
    [Key]
    public int SeismicId { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string? PROCESSING { get; set; } = "";
    public string? SPS { get; set; } = "";
    public string? RPS { get; set; } = "";
    public string? XPS { get; set; } = "";
    public string? OBSERVER_LOG_REPORT { get; set; } = "";
    public string? FINAL_STACK { get; set; } = "";
    public string? RAW_DATA { get; set; } = "";
}
```

If there are better solution

Comment: you use `data : seismics` instead `data: JSON.stringify(seismics)`

Comment: I dont know why my data didnt pass to the controller, the data count still 0 as mention below
"-  seismics Count = 0 System.Collections.Generic.List<BulkyBookWeb.Models.Seismic>"

Comment: Did you try remove Json.Stringfy?

Comment: yes, i did it already after you commented

Comment: can you share model of `Seismic`?

Comment: please you could add to question.

Comment: ah im sorry, its updated